# apk compiled for targetsdk 19(kitkat), works on sdk v21(Lollipop) device

Tags: android, android-studio, android-version

```
productFlavors {
    kkandbelow {
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 19
        applicationId 'bla.bla'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    landabove {
        minSdkVersion 21
        applicationId 'bla.bla'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
}
```

flavor `kkandbelow` compiled apk is a valid installer file on android-21(marshmallow)? 
  Though the targetSdkversion specified as 19, the apk is still installing on androd 5.0.1 device. **Is this behavior expected?**

Comment: Yes, this is expected behaviour. The device will emulate an API-19 environment when running this app.

Comment: yes, since it does not limit max SDK.

Comment: @Henry, this  lead to app malfunction. say, API depricated on 21, will produce  wrong results.

Comment: No, as I said, the device will provide the old functionality (well, at least as long as the old API is not too old).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Is this behavior expected?** 
Yes, it is. You still can apk with lower target sdk version on newer OS versions, it's back compatibility principe.

For more information you can check [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html).

The only one thing you should be worried about when install old apks on newer versions - it's major security changes, like file system access, runtime permissions, etc. These things could lead to crash and needs to be adopted in code.